# How to add transaction manager for jms in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jms

I am using Spring Boot & Spring Data JPA in my application. Now I am working on integrating JMS into my application. After I added the following codes I will see an error when querying the DB.

```java
@Configuration
public class ActiveMQProducerConfig {
   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager createTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
   }
}
```

```
No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!]
```

From my understanding the error is because application cannot find transaction manager for JPA, and it should be caused by my JmsTransactionManager config. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Spring beans are named per the method by default if no `name` value is given to the bean. Per the error message either add the `@Qualifier` annotation and name it per the rror message to `transactionmanger`, rename hte method to `transactionmanager` or add the `name = "transactionmanager" to the `Bean` annnotation.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe thanks for your quick reply. I need to use ```transactional``` annotation for both jms and jpa, and maybe for both at the same time. Will spring boot know which ```transactionmanager``` to use? Spring boot automatically adds configuration for jpa transaction

Comment: @PLee, did you find a solution? I'm getting the same problem

Comment: @Arzybek, sorry, I did not get a solution for it

Answer (score 0):

The `JmsTransactionManager` is only capable of managing transactions on a single JMS connection factory.  So, for example, if you have JMS connection factory and create one or more JMS connections with that factory, then you can use the `JmsTransactionManager`.  The `JmsTransactionManager` will not help you with JPA.

Are you using a proper JTA transaction manager?  You will need this to coordinate transactions if you have a JMS transaction and a JPA transaction in the same transaction context.  You say that Spring Boot automatically includes support for JPA transactions.  This is not my experience.

If you do not have a proper JTA transaction manager configured, I would recommend adding either to your `pom.xml` file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-narayana</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-bitronix</artifactId                
    </dependency>
```

Both of these starters will add a JTA transaction manager to your Spring Boot project and wire the JTA transaction manager in as the `PlatformTransactionManager`.  All components look for the `PlatformTransactionManager` by default.  You should not have to help Spring Boot find your transaction manager or create your own.  You should ensure that the JTA transaction manager is configured as the `PlatformTransactionManager` by using an appropriate Spring Boot starter.

The first starter includes the Arjuna transaction manager.  Configure logging as:

```
<logger name="com.arjuna" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

and you will get some useful logging from Arjuna.

Or:

```
<logger name="bitronix" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

for the Bitronix transaction manager.

I hope that this is helpful.